# How do we prove that $\|A\| - \|B\| \leq \|A+B\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then:
\begin{equation}
\|A\| - \|B\| \leq \|A+B\|.
\end{equation}
Question: How is the inequality derived?

My attempt: Using the triangle inequality:
\begin{equation}
\|A\| = \|A+B-B\| \leq \|A+B\|+\|B\|\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\|A\| - \|B\| \leq \|A+B\|.
\end{equation}

Comment: Please show the own attempts. If the norm-notation stays indeed for a norm, try to move $-\|B\|$ on the other side, then connect the new inequality with the triangle inequality...

Comment: @dan_fulea Ahh, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct. But the proposed result can be improved a little bit.

Indeed, one has:
\begin{align*}
\|A\| = \|A - B + B\| \leq \|A - B\| + \|B\| \Rightarrow \|A - B\| \geq \|A\| - \|B\|
\end{align*}

Similarly, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
\|B\| = \|B - A + A\| \leq \|A - B\| + \|A\| \Rightarrow \|A - B\| \geq \|B\| - \|A\|
\end{align*}

Hence we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
\|A - B\| \geq \max\{\|A\| + \|B\|,-(\|A\| + \|B\|)\} = |\|A\| - \|B\||.
\end{align*}

Such result is particularly useful to prove the norm is a continuous function.

Hopefully this contributes !